# How to understand this equation in a complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

the equation: $$z=z^*u \quad\forall u=e^{i\theta}$$
is said to be line passing through O and in the direction of $u$

I'm stuck. how to understand that?

Comment: This is a line through  the origin but not in the direction of $u$.

Comment: that's also what I thought. this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate must be inccorect by stating  ${\displaystyle {\frac {z-z_{0}}{{\overline {z}}-{\overline {z_{0}}}}}=u}$ is the line through ${\displaystyle z_{0}}z_{0}$ in the direction of $u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. Then, $z=z^*u $ becomes

$$x+iy = (x-iy)e^{i\theta}=(x-iy)(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)
=(\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)+i(\sin\theta-y\cos\theta)$$

which leads to

$$x=x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta,\>\>\>\>\>y=x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta$$

Rearrange the equalities to get,

$$\sin \frac\theta2 \left(y\cos\frac\theta2-x\sin\frac\theta2 \right)=0,\>\>\>\>\>
\cos\frac\theta2 \left(y\cos\frac\theta2-x\sin\frac\theta2 \right)=0$$

Since $\sin \frac\theta2$ and $\cos\frac\theta2$ cannot  be zero at the same time,

$$y\cos\frac\theta2-x\sin\frac\theta2=0$$

Thus, $z$ represents a line passing through O and with its tangent angle  $\theta/2$.

Comment: one can arrive at the conclusion instantly with polar notation of $z$. this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate states that ${\displaystyle {\frac {z-z_{0}}{{\overline {z}}-{\overline {z_{0}}}}}=u}$ is the line through ${\displaystyle z_{0}}z_{0}$ in the direction of $u$ is incorrect. it should be tranlation of the bisector of $\text{arg}u$ which pass through $z_0$

Comment: Just edited the page to be "parallel to the bisector of ${\displaystyle {\text{arg}}u}$"